# Make linux samba share visible in windows with subnets

Tags: windows, samba, smb, file-server, turnkey

How do I make my linux samba share visible from a windows client, where the server and the client are in two different subnets?

For my samba share I use the linux fileserver turnkey image. I use `wsdd` to make the samba share visible. The configuration I have works right now, if the fileserver and my windows client are in the same network. When I move the fileserver into its own network, it's not visible anymore, yet reachable by directly entering the IP in the file explorer.

- Windows Client IP: 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.0/24, gateway: 192.168.1.254)
- SMB Share IP: 192.168.0.109 (192.168.0.0/24, gateway: 192.168.0.254)

There is no firewall on the fileserver enabled. The router (OpenWRT) is configured to `accept` Input, Output and Forward from and to the two subnets. I have not added any port forwards or traffic rules.

The wsdd config looks like this:

```
WSDD_PARAMS="-v --workgroup='WORKGROUP'"
```

using `journalctl` I can see, that there are probes coming from my windows client, and it's also resolved, but the fileserver is not visible under `File Explorer > Network`:

````
-- Boot 7326f24c716f438296161fe2d74bf500 --
Apr 25 23:35:32 smb systemd[1]: Started Web Services Dynamic Discovery host daemon.
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,120:wsdd WARNING(pid 300): no interface given, using all interfaces
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,133:wsdd INFO(pid 300): using pre-defined UUID cd0ed126-b7d2-5ee5-9cee-39bfba91dda9
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,145:wsdd INFO(pid 300): joined multicast group ('239.255.255.250', 3702) on 192.168.0.109%eth0
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,146:wsdd INFO(pid 300): scheduling Hello message via eth0 to ('239.255.255.250', 3702)
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,151:wsdd INFO(pid 300): joined multicast group ('ff02::c', 3702, 22364, 2) on fe80::b806:5bff:fefc:a17%eth0
Apr 25 23:35:33 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:35:33,156:wsdd INFO(pid 300): scheduling Hello message via eth0 to ('ff02::c', 3702, 22364, 2)
Apr 25 23:36:20 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:36:20,945:wsdd INFO(pid 300): 192.168.1.50:50376(eth0) - - "Probe urn:uuid:46cb5469-89d0-4bb7-aff0-d6635b241f59 UDP" - -
Apr 25 23:36:21 smb wsdd[300]: 2023-04-25 23:36:21,041:wsdd INFO(pid 300): 192.168.1.50:50378(eth0) - - "Resolve urn:uuid:3df915df-1802-4602-9ca1-41219fa53411 UDP" - -```
````